# Optimization of double integral function to calibrate parameters

Tags: matlab, optimization, symbolic-math, fminsearch

I have an integral that looks like that:

[image]

I want to the values of ai that minimize H.

I am trying to replicate the example from a [book](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=3D5DA7B295248B44119BCCF074C1D19B) (example 8.1), where the authors say they used GA/fminsearch in MATLAB.

I am not very familiar with MATLAB, but I tried (with no success) to solve it there. I am not sure if I should (or if I can) pass a symbolic equation into `fminsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

```
int_term = @(a) integral2(@(u,v) exp(-a(1)*u - a(2)*u.^2  - a(3)*v ...
    - a(4)*v.^2 - a(5)*u.*v),0,1,0,1);

a0 = [1,1,1,1,1]; 

obj_fun = @(a) int_term2(a);
a_sol = fminsearch(obj_fun2, a0)
```